# Erase all sensitive Google Chrome data from a Windows PC

Tags: windows, google-chrome, security

I want to pass my Windows 8 PC to a different person. There are some sensitive data on that PC, mainly Google Chrome data. (Stored website passwords, cookies, local/session storage, probably something more). My account on that PC is protected with a Windows password.

What's the best procedure to erase that data, if I want to keep the OS?

Comment: Reinstall or recover the OS (factory reset), obviously.

Comment: OP said he wants to keep the OS

Comment: @Geo.Dude Either way it's the same OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft suggests [following way](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17085/windows-8-restore-refresh-reset-pc) (you mentioned you want to avoid reinstalling, but I personally would do it only this way by giving my PC away):

> If you want to recycle your PC, give it away, or start over with it,
>   you can reset it completely. To reset your PC
>
> ```
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap Change PC settings.
> 2. Tap or click Update and recovery, and then tap or click Recovery.
> 3. Under Remove everything and reinstall Windows, tap or click Get started.
> 4. Follow the instructions on the screen.
> ```